# Is Artur Hawkwing a greater Ta'veren than the three Two Rivers boys?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

As referenced by Loial in The Dragon Reborn. Artur Hawkwing was a great Ta'veren. It seems that he stand out among other great hero in the Age of Legends. How does his Ta'veren property compare to the 3 Two Rivers boys?

> "As the Wheel of Time weaves us into the Pattern, the life-thread of
>   each of us pulls and tugs at the life-threads around us. Ta’veren are
>   the same, only much, much more so. They tug at the entire Pattern—for
>   a time, at least—forcing it to shape around them. The closer you are
>   to them, the more you are affected personally. It’s said that if you
>   were in the same room with Artur Hawkwing, you could feel the Pattern
>   rearranging itself. I don’t know how true that is, but I’ve read that
>   it was. But it doesn’t only work one way. Ta’veren themselves are
>   woven to a tighter line than the rest of us, with fewer choices."

Answer (score 9):

I don't know specifically about Perrin or Mat, but it's well established that Rand, as the reincarnation of Lews Therin, is the strongest *ta'veren* in history. In particular, compare Loial's description of Hawkwing to the description of Rand's

> post-come-to-Jesus meeting with newly-crowned Amyrlin Egwene

where she could literally feel the pattern trying to pull her into agreeing with Rand, and the rest of the people present claimed they could scarcely think, let alone act freely.

We never see anything this strong from Mat or Perrin. This implies that Hawkwing would be more strongly *ta'veren* than with of those two, but less so than Rand.

Comment: I think it's also outright stated throughout the series that Hawkwing is 2nd only to Rand, implying that Mat and Perrin are less.

Comment: +1 on both of you. Ranking (pattern-chlorians any one? :p) would go Rand > Arthur > Mat > Perrin I think. We have seen scenes with Mat where the Pattern seems to be groaning when he does an impossible dice throw.

Comment: @jv42 I'm not sure than *all* of Mat's ridiculous luck is because of his being *ta'veren*; it seems to be something deeper for him, much like Perrin's wolfness. AFAICT neither Mat not Perrin has ever influenced the other to act, while Rand has clearly pulled both of them along in his wake.

Comment: I agree, his luck is not being ta'veren. Sometimes his gambles' results are though.

Comment: @jv42 and Michael Edenfield: Re. Mat's luck, see also [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/65256/where-does-mats-luck-come-from).

Answer (score 7):

A canon reference for Artur Hawkwing being a lesser *ta'veren* than Rand, as @KutuluMike said:

> "No one knows anything about *ta'veren* as strong as Rand." For just a moment she sounded vexed at not knowing. "Artur Hawkwing was the most strongly *ta'veren* of whom any writings remain. And Hawkwing was in no way as strong as Rand."
>
> <sub>-- Moiraine, Book 3: *The Dragon Reborn*, Chapter 8: *Jarra*</sub>